# MongoDb : Find and filter values from nested map

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some date in mongo db

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "orgId": "606abce197dc265ac41ae82c",
    "registrations": {
      "id1": {
        "status": "status",
        "topStage": {
          "id": "stage1",
          "name": "stage1"
        }
      },
      "id2": {
        "status": "status",
        "topStage": {
          "id": "stage1",
          "name": "stage1"
        }
      },
      "id3": {
        "status": "status",
        "topStage": {
          "id": "stage2",
          "name": "stage2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am expecting to pass a stage id (at path registrations-> topStage -> id) and return all matching key values.

i have written following query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      teams: {
        $objectToArray: "$registrations"
      },
      original: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "teams": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$teams",
          "as": "team",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$team.v.topStage.id",
              "stage1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "registrations": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$teams"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It does return me right values
for stage1 as stage id

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "registrations": {
      "id1": {
        "status": "status",
        "topStage": {
          "id": "stage1",
          "name": "stage1"
        }
      },
      "id2": {
        "status": "status",
        "topStage": {
          "id": "stage1",
          "name": "stage1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and for stage2 as stage id, it returns

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "registrations": {
      "id3": {
        "status": "status",
        "topStage": {
          "id": "stage2",
          "name": "stage2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Can someone let me know if this is the best way to write this query or this can be simplified ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the correct way to do it but there will be performance impact in the following cases.

- If you don't have any other match condition against the indices
- if you have a match condition and it matches few docs where registrations has more objects

Other best option you could do is that altering the schema.

- you can keep registrations.id1 as `registrations : { id:1, status_id: 2}`
- or you could alter the way such that it will not need to use objectToArray on larger set
- if your data is huge, I would recommend to add an index on nested status Id field.

And mongo documentation itself suggests to evaluate multiple schemas for any data to get the best out of it.